# Fuseki Web App - Fuseki Base on Windows

Tags: windows, jena, fuseki

I'd like to use Fuseki Web App on Windows. I already tried to use Fuseki on MacOS, I created the /etc/fuseki folder (with the right privileges): no problem with it. But on Windows the deployment failed maybe because the folder doesn't exist (fuseki doesn't find the folder).
Where should I create this folder? Should I define the FUSEKI_BASE as environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/etc/fuseki` is a unix-ish way of doing things. You can do that if you want to or you can define `FUSEKI_BASE`. The choice is yours.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But so I should define FUSEKI_BASE as environment variable on Windows?

Comment: Yes - and ensure that environment variable is available to the running application.